# Returning From a Function BEFORE disposing sqlconnection

Tags: sql, vb.net

I should begin by stating that I assume that the answer to this question is NO, but I wanted to ask to be sure.....If you open a sqlconnection inside of a function(with a USING block), and return from that function prior to reaching the end of the block, will that connection be disposed of properly?

For Example:

```
 Public Function Myfunction() As Boolean

        Dim ConnectionString As String = "connectionstring goes here"

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM mytable"

        Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                connection.Open()
                Using reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                    While reader.Read
                            Return True
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Return False

    End Function
```

Will the above connection be disposed of properly if the return true line is executed?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you open a sqlconnection inside of a function(with a USING block), and return from that function prior to reaching the end of the block, will that connection be disposed of properly?

Yes.  Absolutely.  That's the beauty of a USING block. See

> A Using block behaves like a Try...Finally construction in which the Try block uses the resources and the Finally block disposes of them. Because of this, the Using block guarantees disposal of the resources, **no matter how you exit the block**. This is true even in the case of an unhandled exception, except for a StackOverflowException

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement